# Not all the icons have changed after installing a new icon theme in Lubuntu

Tags: themes, icons, lubuntu, directory, pcmanfm

I have installed an icon theme in Lubuntu. Icons have changed but not every icon. Folder icons are the same but there are many more icons for music folder, video folder etc. Opera has new icon, but they didn't change.

What should I do to change all the icons from the new icon theme?

I am using PCManFM as my file manager in Lubuntu.

Comment: suggestion you add details of the theme you are trying together with how you installed it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the icon theme. If the icon theme contains icons for every mimetype and application, they'd be changed.

To confirm that this, indeed, is the case, download *Faenza Icon Theme* (it contains almost all the icons) and see if it works.

To install *Faenza Icon Theme*, open a terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tiheum/equinox
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install faenza-icon-theme
```

Comment: thnaks,my icon theme have all the icons i think, for example icon called opera.png, folder-downloads.png but theyre not changed.

Comment: did you try logging out and logging back in?

Comment: with faenza, opera changed icon, but the music, films...folders are the same as all the folders, i think it must do something with the PcManFM, or i dont, my folder icons for media are still not changed.